# Get the distance between my position and the fetched record's location with Algolia on Android

Tags: android, google-maps, firebase, algolia

I am using Algolia's [InstantSearch Android](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android) library. This is my `Query`:

```
searcher.setQuery(new Query().setAroundLatLng(new AbstractQuery.LatLng(lat, lng)).setAroundRadius(5000)).
```

How can I display the distance between the fetched record and my current location?

Comment: Get the current location, calculate the distance and then show it on the UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on top of @Raphi's great answer, here's how you can display the distance with InstantSearch Android: you just have to write a **custom Hit `View`**.

- Create a [Custom hit view](https://community.algolia.com/instantsearch-android/widgets.html#custom-hit-views): here a specialized `TextView` implementing [`AlgoliaHitView`](https://github.com/algolia/instantsearch-android/blob/master/instantsearch/src/main/java/com/algolia/instantsearch/ui/views/AlgoliaHitView.java)
- in `onUpdateView`, get the `_rankingInfo.matchedGeoLocation.distance` as Raphi recommended
- use this value in your View, for example with `setText(distance + " meters away.")`

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can find the distance in the response for every hit by adding the parameter `getRankingInfo=true` to your search query.

I'm not familiar with InstantSearch Android but if you have access to the raw response, then look at `_rankingInfo.matchedGeoLocation.distance` in your records:

```
{
  [...] // your record fields
  "_rankingInfo": {
    "nbTypos": 0,
    "firstMatchedWord": 0,
    "proximityDistance": 0,
    "userScore": 11,
    "geoDistance": 468,
    "geoPrecision": 1,
    "nbExactWords": 1,
    "words": 1,
    "filters": 0,
    "matchedGeoLocation": {
      "lat": 48.86,
      "lng": 2.3443,
      "distance": 468
    }
  }
}
```

See https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/searching/geo-search/?language=rails#identifying-the-matching-geo-search-with-rankinginfo

Comment: Thanks a lot brother

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class named as `CalculateDistanceTime` and paste below code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

class CalculateDistanceTime {

    private taskCompleteListener mTaskListener;
    private Context mContext;


    CalculateDistanceTime(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    void setLoadListener(taskCompleteListener taskListener) {
        mTaskListener = taskListener;
    }


    void getDirectionsUrl(LatLng origin, LatLng dest) {

        // Origin of route
        String str_origin = "origin=" + origin.latitude + "," + origin.longitude;

        // Destination of route
        String str_dest = "destination=" + dest.latitude + "," + dest.longitude;


        // Sensor enabled
        String sensor = "sensor=false";

        // Building the parameters to the web service
        String parameters = str_origin + "&" + str_dest + "&" + sensor;

        // Output format
        String output = "json";

        // Building the url to the web service
        String url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/" + output + "?" + parameters;


        DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();

        // Start downloading json data from Google Directions API

        downloadTask.execute(url);
    }

    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException {
        String data = "";
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection;
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        try (InputStream iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream()) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            data = sb.toString();

            br.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("Excp. while downloading", e.toString());
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
        return data;
    }


    interface taskCompleteListener {
        void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance);
    }

    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

        // Downloading data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

            // For storing data from web service
            String data = "";

            try {
                // Fetching the data from web service
                data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Background Task", e.toString());
            }
            return data;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the execution of
        // doInBackground()
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);

            ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

            // Invokes the thread for parsing the JSON data
            parserTask.execute(result);

        }
    }

    private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, List<HashMap<String, String>>> {

        // Parsing the data in non-ui thread
        @Override
        protected List<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

            JSONObject jObject;
            List<HashMap<String, String>> routes = null;

            try {
                jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);
                DistanceTimeParser parser = new DistanceTimeParser();

                // Starts parsing data
                routes = parser.parse(jObject);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return routes;
        }

        // Executes in UI thread, after the parsing process
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<HashMap<String, String>> result) {

            String duration_distance = "";


            if (result.size() < 1) {
                Log.e("Error : ", "No Points found");
                return;
            }


            String[] date_dist = new String[2];

            // Traversing through all the routes
            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {

                // Fetching i-th route
                HashMap<String, String> tmpData = result.get(i);
                Set<String> key = tmpData.keySet();
                Iterator it = key.iterator();
                while (it.hasNext()) {
                    String hmKey = (String) it.next();
                    duration_distance = tmpData.get(hmKey);

                    System.out.println("Key: " + hmKey + " & Data: " + duration_distance);

                    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
                }

                date_dist[i] = duration_distance;
            }

            mTaskListener.taskCompleted(date_dist);
        }
    }
}
```

Then use below code wherever you want to show distance and time.
Create a global variable, `CalculateDistanceTime distance_task;`
and then, use this code

```
                    distance_task.getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, latLng2);
                    distance_task.setLoadListener(new CalculateDistanceTime.taskCompleteListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void taskCompleted(String[] time_distance) {
                            v1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            text1.setText(time_distance[0]); //Distance
                            text2.setText(time_distance[1]); //Time
                        }
                    });
```

See, text1 and text2 here are two textviews used to display Distance and Time respectively.
Also, the major thing is see the class call here, `distance_task.getDirectionsUrl(latLng1, latLng2);`, here latLng1 is source and latLng2 is destination and you should provide these two latLngs for it to work.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother

Comment: Although this is a valid way to calculate the distance from the coordinates, see @Raphi's answer and mine which tell you how to *get* the distance from Algolia's response **without doing more network calls**.